# How can I change the placeholder color of a UITextField?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, colors, uitextfield, placeholder

I have tried the two options everybody answers in this forum but nothing works for me... I have tried to override:

`- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect`

and also:

`[self.myTextField setValue:[UIColor redColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];`

but nothing happens... Still the same gray color... Maybe I have to inherit something, I don't know... Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the simplest way to do this:

```
UILabel *placeholderAppearance;
if (@available(iOS 9, *)) {
    placeholderAppearance = [UILabel appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UITextField class]]];
} else {
    placeholderAppearance = [UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITextField class], nil];
}
placeholderAppearance.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

**[EDITED]**
After using this I got to know another bug, the above did the job but it also reset the color of all other labels in my view to Default Black. Then to overcome this, I had to sub class the UILabel class and use my class in all other labels in my view.

Comment: thanks! one more thing: is it possible to also change the editing blue vertical bar color?

Comment: Don't really know about this but I would like to add something to the above placeholder work around. After using this I got to know another bug, the above did the job but it also reset the color of all other labels in my view to Default Black. Then to overcome this, I had to sub class the UILabel class and use my class in all other labels in my view.

Answer (score 1):

See `drawPlaceholderInRect:` of `UITextField`. You need to subclass UITextField and override this method for configuring graphics context with desired text color and call super implementation.

> By the time this method is called, the current graphics context is
>   already configured with the default environment and text color for
>   drawing. In your overridden method, you can configure the current
>   context further and then invoke super to do the actual drawing or do
>   the drawing yourself. If you do render the text yourself, you should
>   not invoke super.

Answer (score 0):

From iOS6 you can use the attributed placeholder:

```
textfield.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textfield.placeholder attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]}];
```